# how to avoid user get into the login session even after logging out by clicking back?

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a login form. It works fine, but it goes back to the logged in page if the user clicks back button after they log out.
When I tried something to stop it, the index page stopped working. It shows problem loading page error.

I have done this in my index page to avoid the user not to go back to logged in session but now the index page itself doesn't work.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    header('Location:index.php');
}
```

logout.php:

```
session_start();#This will start the session
session_unset(); #Session_unset and Session_destroy
session_destroy();#Will remove all sessions.

header("location:index.php");#This code will sen du back to the index page
```

Once the user logs in the user logs in to this home page. I have added session like this:

```
session_start();

$user = $_SESSION['user'];
```

Please correct me where I am wrong. The problems I am facing are:

1. to make my index page display
2. avoid user going back to their logged in session after logging out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could help people who will be looking for the same issue..!

To avoid the  back button getting into your home page after logging out.paste the below code after altering with your session key and variable

```
<?

session_start();

$user = $_SESSION['user'];

if ($_SESSION['user'] == ""){

  header('LOCATION:index.php');

}
?>
```

This will go to the home page as the browser redirects and then the homepage will direct back to the index page if the session is empty (note that the session will be destroyed once the user clicks logout)

Answer (score 2):

[Follow the Post/Redirect/Get pattern.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)

> Post/Redirect/Get (PRG) is a common design pattern for web developers
>   to help avoid certain duplicate form submissions and allow user agents
>   to behave more intuitively with bookmarks and the refresh button.
>
> When a web form is submitted to a server through an HTTP POST request,
>   a web user that attempts to refresh the server response in certain
>   user agents can cause the contents of the original HTTP POST request
>   to be resubmitted, possibly causing undesired results, such as a
>   duplicate web purchase.

**Useful Reads:**

- [Redirect After Post](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1365146/Redirect-After-Post)
- [How to avoid POSTDATA resend warning](http://www.ajaxray.com/blog/2008/01/12/how-to-avoid-postdata-resend-warning/)

---

The simplest you can do also is to put a condition in the header.php (or similar file which is shared across):

```
session_start(); // on top of the scrit
................
...............

if (! isset($_SESSION['yourKey'])){
  header('LOCATION: notLoggedPage.php');
  exit;
}
```

**Note:** Make sure to put `session_start()` at the start of your script whenever you have session-related functions in your script.

Answer (score 0):

If user click "Back" button, browser will not reload the page and just display it.

You should do something to disable features in those pages that user should login first.